# Adding an element in a vector space with an element from a proper subspace of that vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be a proper subspace of a vector space $V$ and let $\vec{x} \in S$ and $\vec{y} \in V, \notin S$.

Clearly $\vec{x} + \vec{y} \in V$, by closure of $V$ under addition, but can we have $\vec{x}+\vec{y} \in S$? An example demonstrating either outcome would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If $\vec x+\vec y=\vec s\in S$ then $\vec y=\vec s-\vec x\in S$.

Comment: Very concise, thank you! I had the suspicion that it couldn't work but I couldn't quite put my finger on why. This explains it well.